# sklearn pca's n_component equals to the number of features problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

When I don't set the `n_components` parameter, the number of components kept equals the number of features of the dataframe.

If `n_components` isn't set, then the transformed dataframe should be the same, but it turns out that it is not.

Why is the transformed dataframe different from the original dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd
pca = PCA(random_state=seed)
pd1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])
pca.fit(pd1)
print(pd1)
print(pca.transform(pd1))
```

the output is:

```
0  1  2
0  1  1  1
1  2  2  2
2  3  3  3
[[-1.73205081e+00 -1.11022302e-16  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.73205081e+00  1.11022302e-16  0.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: Because sklearn is supposed to provide a different output... that's what it's for no?....

Answer (score 3):

The documentation in [sklearn pca page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) says

```
n_components == min(n_samples, n_features)
```

So that is the reason why your result has 3 components.

And then PCA will just do its thing by converting your data to those 3 principal axes where the variance is maximized (and orthogonal).

To get a more mathematical explanation on what PCA does, please check other sources like [PCA wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)